# MVC3 Razor Views Intellisense not detecting model object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been having an issue with mvc views on our website, where the view doesn't seem to detect the model type. I'll get an error message like 'model doesn't exist in the current context.', and and I'll get a red line under the model. It doesn't detect classes in the model either, and will try put an error line underneath the Html helpers.  However, when I build the project and run it, it works fine.  I've tried numerous suggestions on Stack Overflow, most involving changes to the config files, however nothing works.  Here is what I have in the system.web section of my web.config:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ShowError">
```

```
    <siteMap defaultProvider="AgilitySiteMapProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="AgilitySiteMapProvider" type="Agility.Web.Providers.AgilitySiteMapProvider, Agility.Web" />
        </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="Agility.Web" />
            <add namespace="Agility.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="CineplexWebsite.Helpers" />
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="Agility" assembly="Agility.Web" namespace="Agility.Web.Controls" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </controls>
    </pages>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<authentication mode="None">

</authentication>
```

and here is what I have in my views web.config

```
<system.web>

 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/ShowError">
```

```
    <siteMap defaultProvider="AgilitySiteMapProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="AgilitySiteMapProvider" type="Agility.Web.Providers.AgilitySiteMapProvider, Agility.Web" />
        </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            <add namespace="Agility.Web" />
            <add namespace="Agility.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="CineplexWebsite.Helpers" />
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="Agility" assembly="Agility.Web" namespace="Agility.Web.Controls" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </controls>
    </pages>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<authentication mode="None">

</authentication>
```

Any idea what is causing this? Am I missing a dll reference?

Comment: what happens with you add a `@using CineplexWebsite.Helpers` to the top of your view?

Comment: same issue - I get a red line under any of the helpers in the view, but when I build the project and run it, it works fine.

Comment: Build the project once and see if references come in.

Answer (score 2):

In your project there are 2 `web.config` files:

- in root of project
- in Views folder

You should add your `<add namespace="CineplexWebsite.Helpers" />` model namespace into config file in Views folder. Usually, it not regocnized. Close and open project again, then it will regocnize.

Comment: I tried this, however, it still doesn't recognize any types I have in my view.  For example, even though my view is strongly-typed, the view is for some reason interpreting the passed object as 'dynamic object - will be evaluated at runtime'.  It doesn't recognize the @model declaration -  there is a red line that say '@model doesn't exist in the current context'

Comment: First, sometimes it shows '@model doesn't exist in the current context', but in runtime it works. Second, maybe your namespace not referenced to you asp.net application..